# SetTimeout don't work correctly

Tags: javascript

I think the pop window with OK string will be dislayed afetr 5s after I click the button, but the pop window dispalyed  immediately after I click the button, why?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wake up call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function wakeUpCall() { // Function is defined here
            setTimeout(aa("ok"), 5000);
        }

        function aa(bb) {
            alert(bb);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <form>
        <input type="button"
            value="Wake me"
            onclick="wakeUpCall()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function wakeUpCall() { // Function is defined here
            setTimeout(function(){ alert("ok");}, 5000);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do it the wrong way.

You have to use a callback for the `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    // actual code here
}, 5000);
```

Mike has provided in his answer - that you could use an evaluatable string:

```
setTimeout('/* actual code here */', 5000);
```

But that is strongly discouraged, use his other example - passing the callback function as a reference and invoking callback arguments.
You have to take in mind, though, that if you are going with callback arguments, see this [section of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Callback_arguments) article. The callback arguments aren't supported in all browsers.

Personally, I'd suggest going with plain old callbacks, because that's how the setTimeout is meant to be used.

Just for your information:

The reason why your snippet isn't working for you, is, because:

```
setTimeout(aa('ok'), 5000);
// aa('ok') here is executed, and returns its value, so, in the end, you pass the returned value of aa inside the Timeout.
// and, nor alert alert, nor your function have a "return" statement, so they both will  return always undefined.
// that translates to:

setTimeout(undefined, 5000); // and, that does nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you would do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wake up call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function wakeUpCall() { // Function is defined here
            setTimeout('aa("ok");', 5000);
        }

        function aa(bb) {
            alert(bb);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <form>
        <input type="button"
            value="Wake me"
            onclick="wakeUpCall()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice I have quoted the statement to execute in the setTimeout function. It those quotes confuse you, I think this is a good resource to take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Another way to do it, I just learned from the resource above, is like this:

```
function wakeUpCall() { // Function is defined here
    setTimeout(aa, 5000, "Your tekst here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use anonymous functions for this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wake up call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function wakeUpCall() { // Function is defined here
            setTimeout(function(){aa("ok");}, 5000);
        }

        function aa(bb) {
            alert(bb);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <form>
        <input type="button"
            value="Wake me"
            onclick="wakeUpCall()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```